# using php to send mail through contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

I have this function and after doing some research i'm still not being able to find out why this isn't working
I am new to PHP and would like some help. thank you.

> sendemail.php

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Mail Sent. Thank you , we will contact you shortly. '
    );

    $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'help@addonevents.in';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
```

> My form

```
<form name="contact-form" method="POST" action="sendemail.php">
                <label>Name *</label>
               <input type="text" name="name" required="required">
                <label>Email *</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required="required">
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input type="number">
                 <label>Subject *</label>
                <input type="text" name="subject" required="required">
                 <label>Message *</label>
                 <textarea name="message"  required="required" rows="8"></textarea>
                 <button type="submit" name="submit" required="required">Submit Message</button>
</form>
```

can anyone help? I am getting the success message but no mail to my inbox
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you used `header('Content-type: application/json');` in your `sendmail.php` file?

Comment: do you get any error..

Comment: check if mail is send correctly using `if(mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>')) { // mail send } else { //mail not send }`

Comment: you can use this http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Comment: @ shankar Prakash.. No error..rather a success message.

Comment: @hardik. that is for my function to determine the type of data im sending back from my echo function below, as I was trying to passing a variable  along with the message through the encode function to display in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, almost nobody uses PHP's `mail` function to send emails professionally. Even [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on that function says:

> It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger
>   volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP
>   socket for each email, which is not very efficient.

I used PHPMailer, which is quite easy to setup and use. I think it is the most popular mailing library in PHP. You can get it [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

The documentation from PHPMailer describes well what is wrong with `mail` function.

> Many PHP developers utilize email in their code. The only PHP function
>   that supports this is the mail() function. However, it does not
>   provide any assistance for making use of popular features such as
>   HTML-based emails and attachments.
>
> Formatting email correctly is surprisingly difficult. There are myriad
>   overlapping RFCs, requiring tight adherence to horribly complicated
>   formatting and encoding rules - the vast majority of code that you'll
>   find online that uses the mail() function directly is just plain
>   wrong! Please don't be tempted to do it yourself - if you don't use
>   PHPMailer, there are many other excellent libraries that you should
>   look at before rolling your own - try SwiftMailer, Zend_Mail,
>   eZcomponents etc.

Here is a small (official) example on how to use PHPMailer:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

So don't reinvent the wheel, and use proven and reliable library to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to php and dint know about PHPMailer. I am currently trying it out. thanks once again.